# Min and Max of a function

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I need to obtain for what $a_i$'s the function:

$$a_1 \ln (\sqrt{2\pi e} s_1) + a_2 \ln (\sqrt{2\pi e} s_2),$$

has a maximum and minimum, under the constraint $a_1 + a_2 = 1$; also, $s_1, s_2 > 0$.

Let's first look at the maximum and minimum of the function:

```
Minimize[{a1 Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s1] + a2 Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s2], a1 + a2 == 1}, {a1, a2}, Reals] // FullSimplify

Maximize[{a1 Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s1] + a2 Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s2], a1 + a2 == 1}, {a1, a2}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

I don't understand the results: besides the fact that, I don't know how Mathematica has calculated the conditions, but also, the results show that for the same condition the value of max and min are equal!

My second question is: how can one from the above, now infer the corresponding values of $a_i$'s?

Comment: I thought the result of `Solve[Thread[D[a1 Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s1] + (1 - a1) Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s2], {{s1, s2}, 1}] == 0], a1]` was pretty informative... (see the fourth bullet under "Details and Options" of `Solve[]`'s doc page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `a1 + a2 == 1` you will get cleaner results by using `(1 - a1)` in place of `a2`. You should also include the constraints that `s1 > 0` and `s2 > 0`

```
({min, max} = (#[{a1 Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s1] + (1 - a1) Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] s2],
         s1 > 0, s2 > 0}, a1] // FullSimplify) & /@ {Minimize, 
     Maximize}) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I had interpreted the $a_k$ to be parameters, while the $s_k$ were the independent variables. @Sam, can you confirm if I had interpreted wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this analytically.

Consider your expression:

[image]

We may replace `a2` by `(1-a1)` and `Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] si]]` by `Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E]+ Log[si]`. Further we may call `Log[Sqrt[2 Pi E] == c`:

```
ex= c + a1 Log[s1] + Log[s2] - a1 Log[s2]
```

For an extremum the derivative relative to a1 must be zero:

```
Log[s1] -  Log[s2] == 0
```

As the Log is monotonic:

```
s1 == s2
```

Let us call this value: s. Then we have:

```
ex= c + Log[s]
```

Therefore, if s->infinity, then Max is + Infinity and the Min is -Infinity. And a1 and a2 drop out.

Comment: Yes, if I did it right, they drop out.